# Adding new objects to a list; (For loop not working properly)

Tags: java, loops, object, for-loop, addition

So I'm trying to add a names to a new list from a file called directory.txt that has 1000 objects that contain a first name, last name, and a phone number; something like this (Dodge, Nick 765-123-2312). When I run the program below without a "for loop" I can add the first object off the .txt file successfully and it prints it out. However when I add a for loop like, for(int i =0; i < 1000; i++), it for some reason jumps to the end off the list and inputs the 1000 object in the first spot and skips the rest. I can't figure this out! Thanks for the help.

new code;

```
 import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  import bsu.edu.cs121.names.Names;
  import bsu.edu.cs121.quickSort.QuickSort;



   public class NameTester {


public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {


    ArrayList<Names> namelist= new ArrayList<Names>();

    Scanner file = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the phone book file: ");
    String newFile = file.next();
    File inputFile = new File("/Users/Latif/Desktop/workspace/CS121 Project4/src/" + newFile);
    Scanner readFile = new Scanner(inputFile);
    while (readFile.hasNextLine()){ //start while

                String lastName = readFile.next();
                String firstName = readFile.nextLine();
                String phoneNumber = readFile.nextLine();
                namelist.add(new Names(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber));


    }


    QuickSort newSort = new QuickSort(namelist);

    System.out.println(namelist.get(1) + " " +  namelist.get(2));




}
```

}

Comment: Can you please remove all the comments and stuff you changed to make it work and actually show us the code that's -not- working? It's kinda hard to tell what here is just the way it is because you changed it to make it work.

Comment: Also, what is `Names nameslist[]  = new Names[1000];` supposed to be, that's not valid Java, far as I know.

Comment: One more thing, is `Names` a class for -one- name (in that case, why is it plural?) or what?

Comment: Ok I think I removed all the comments for you; my theory was to import the file which contains 1000 names and phone numbers and then create a new Name object by sending that information to the Name class which I have added above. The nameslist[] was used to create a new list that I could search through; I may be completely off on this. And I apologize Names was supposed to be Name I just accidentally wrote it that way and went with it. I'll change it.

Comment: Once I have the names on a list; I have to then be able to search through it using binary search by the name and return the phone number or the other way around.

Comment: Hmmm, so what output does this give you? Is it like... it gives the 1000th entry for the first spot (are you sure it's the first spot?), then just nothing for the rest?

Comment: (Just as a sidenote, if your goal is fast access to data, I would actually recommend using HashMap instead of an array, it's probably better worth it just to have two Maps, one keyed to names, the other to numbers.)

Comment: I'll look into that; and Sorry I'm pretty much a beginner when it comes to Java so a lot of this stuff is Greek to me! Trying to learn.

Comment: Maybe try, say, reducing the size of the file to just 10 phone numbers or such, so you can post the file and the output for us? With the array size also set to 10, ofc.

Comment: This is a new attempt that seems to be working; I can print out namelist.toString( ) and all the names are there. Now I just have to figure out how to use a quickSort method to sort it properly and then a binary search for finding names and numbers. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Ah well, you can sort just by calling the sort method if you're using a list. For search, look into [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28byte[],%20byte%29).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are inserting the name data into index [0] of your nameslist array every time, so every loop you are replacing your previous data and at the very end you end up with one item that equals your last entry.  You need to assign the proper array index to each.

```
nameslist[i] = new Names(first, last, number);
```

Comment: well I had the namelist[0] there just to test I was reading the file correctly; if I use the 0 I get the first name from the directory; However if I use the namelist[i] it jumps to the last name and prints the other 999 spaces null.

Comment: and I don't quite no how to to work this "if your Names class can be assigned new values without creating a new object, I would do that too."

Comment: yeah, forget about that last one, I've been working a bit in c++ so I got a little confused, it's not the case here.  I've deleted it.